# Modifying a UDF Concatenate to Remove Duplicates

Tags: excel, vba, concatenation, vlookup

I've got a custom vlookup that I'd like to modify to remove duplicates before concatenation.  [This is the data I've got put together.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPpec.png) I'm taking the feature names from Column A and removing duplicates to create unique data to use the custom Vlookup on in the F column.

In the F column, I am using this Excel Function: 
    `{=IFERROR(INDEX(A$2:A$12,MATCH(0,COUNTIF(F$1:F2,A$2:A$12),0)),"")}`

From here I am using a UDF that selects the code to the left of it, then searches through the table to find feature names that match, then extracting the location codes to be put into a concatenate that spaces out the names. This is what I have in VBA for a module.

```
`Function CusVlookup(FeatureName As String, pWorkRng As Range, pIndex As Long)
  Dim rng As Range
   Dim xResult As String
    xResult = ""
    For Each rng In pWorkRng
     If rng = FeatureName Then
     xResult = xResult & ", " & rng.Offset(0, pIndex - 1)
      If Left(xResult, 2) = ", " Then
      xResult = Mid(xResult, 2, 255)
   End If
  End If
  Next
  CusVlookup = xResult
  End Function`
```

The function used in cell G3 is as follows:
     `=cusvlookup(F3,A2:E12,5)`

This is my first real foray into VBA, and the code I have was what I could find sifting through google searches and on here. All I need this code to do is to remove duplicate values before concatenation, but an explanation of what is happening would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a little change in your function. Note the Range below is A2:A14 (not like A2:E12 in your code). .. For INSTR VBA Function Check [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function)

```
Function CusVlookup(FeatureName As String, pWorkRng As Range, pIndex As Long)
Dim rng As Range
Dim xResult As String
xResult = ""

For Each rng In pWorkRng
    If rng = FeatureName And InStr(1, xResult, rng.Offset(0, pIndex - 1) & ",") = 0 Then
        If xResult = "" Then
        xResult = rng.Offset(0, pIndex - 1) & ", "
        Else
        xResult = xResult & rng.Offset(0, pIndex - 1) & ", "
        End If
    End If
Next

CusVlookup = Mid(xResult, 1, Len(xResult) - 2)
End Function
```

You can Step into following procedure (debug using F8 Key) to understand what is happening in your function.

```
Sub test()
Dim FeatureName As String: FeatureName = Range("F3").Value
Dim pWorkRng As Range: Set pWorkRng = Range("A2:A12")
Dim pIndex As Long: pIndex = 5

Dim rng As Range
Dim xResult As String
xResult = ""

For Each rng In pWorkRng
    If rng = FeatureName And InStr(1, xResult, rng.Offset(0, pIndex - 1) & ",") = 0 Then
        If xResult = "" Then
        xResult = rng.Offset(0, pIndex - 1) & ", "
        Else
        xResult = xResult & rng.Offset(0, pIndex - 1) & ", "
        End If
    End If
Next

Debug.Print Mid(xResult, 1, Len(xResult) - 2)

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This works perfectly! I'll try to use that debug tool to look up specific functions as well.